# Free form String for Parameter in AppIntent? requestValueDialog works, but filters responses and does not permit words like "last" or "recent"

Tags: ios, swift, siri, appintents

We have a simple AppIntent to let users ask a question in our app.

The intent has a single parameter: Prompt which is retrieved by a requestValueDialog and needs to be a free form String.

Users have reported that when using Siri, the dialog for "What would you like to ask?" appears, but if they respond with phrases such as "What is the last album by Sting" it just presents the dialog for the prompt again.

All of the Siri interaction happens outside our code, so I cant see any way to debug or identify why the prompts are being rejected. Is there a different way to specify the Parameter to indicate the prompt String could include any arbitrary text - including "recent" or "last" ?

My hunch is those words are triggering a system response or disambiguation that is stepping on the requstValueDialog?

Here is a video showing two failure cases and then a prompt that it does accept:
https://youtube.com/shorts/v2j51T7Kdxw

Testing it, I find that I can reproduce the behavior if I include words like "recent" or "last". Just providing those words in isolation causes the dialog to be presented over and over again.Using the same intent from Shortcuts does not seem to have that limitation, it's only when providing the spoken words for speech recognition.

Here's how the AppIntent and Parameter are setup:

```
struct AskAI: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Ask"
    static var description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("This will ask the A.I. app")
    static var openAppWhenRun = false
    
    @Parameter(title: "Prompt", description: "The prompt to send", requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("What would you like to ask?"))
    var prompt: String
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog & ShowsSnippetView {
        var response = ""
...
        response = "You asked: \"\(prompt)\"  \n"
...
        return .result(dialog: "\(response)")
    }
    
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Ask \(\.$prompt)")
    }
}
```

The goal is to get Siri to ask the user for a prompt and accept the string for what they say without filtering.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm struggling with a similar issue. If i want to input a free text and mention something with a currency like 30€, it always tells me, that there is no app available to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same thing: Siri keeps repeating the question. However, I found out that if I leave out the `requestValueDialog` in the `@Parameter` macro, it works as intended. Siri generates a generic question instead (which I'm not happy with).

This fails, as in, Siri keeps repeating the question in a loop:

```swift
@Parameter(title: "Journal", requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("Which journal do you want to update?"))
```

This works, in the sense that Siri gets the user's answer to the question and continues:

```swift
@Parameter(title: "Journal")
```